# Upload Pandas dataframe as a JSON object in Cloud Storage

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have been trying to upload a Pandas dataframe to a JSON object in Cloud Storage using Cloud Function.  Follwing is my code -

```
def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
"""Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
   bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
   blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

   blob.upload_from_file(source_file_name)

   print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
    source_file_name,
    destination_blob_name))

final_file = pd.concat([df, df_second], axis=0)
final_file.to_json('/tmp/abc.json')
with open('/tmp/abc.json', 'r') as file_obj:
   upload_blob('test-bucket',file_obj,'abc.json')
```

I am getting the following error in line - blob.upload_from_file(source_file_name)

```
Deployment failure:
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file main.py 
can't be loaded.
Detailed stack trace: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 305, in 
check_or_load_user_function
_function_handler.load_user_function()
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 184, in load_user_function
spec.loader.exec_module(main)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/user_code/main.py", line 6, in <module>
import datalab.storage as gcs
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datalab/storage/__init__.py", 
line 16, in <module>
from ._bucket import Bucket, Buckets
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datalab/storage/_bucket.py", 
line 21, in <module>
import datalab.context
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datalab/context/__init__.py", 
line 15, in <module>
from ._context import Context
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datalab/context/_context.py", 
line 20, in <module>
from . import _project
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datalab/context/_project.py", 
line 18, in <module>
import datalab.utils
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datalab/utils/__init__.py", 
line 15
from ._async import async, async_function, async_method
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What possibly is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to [blob.upload_from_file()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_file), but this method requires a file object. You probably want to use [blob.upload_from_filename()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_filename) instead. Check the sample in [the GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python).

Alternatively, you could get the file object, and keep using blob.upload_from_file(), but it's unnecessary extra lines.

```py
with open('/tmp/abc.json', 'r') as file_obj:
    upload_blob('test-bucket', file_obj, 'abc.json')
```

Comment: I am getting error -

Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file main.py can't be loaded.

Comment: Try running what you had before, but just change blob.upload_from_file() to blob.upload_from_filename().

Answer (score -1):

Use a bucket object instead of string

something like `upload_blob(conn.get_bucket(mybucket),'/tmp/abc.json','abc.json')}`

Comment: I am using this in the 'upload_blob()' function.

Comment: you can do it one single sentence. 

`import datalab.storage as gcs

gcs.Bucket('bucketName').item('to/data.csv').write_to(simple_dataframe.to_csv(),'text/csv’)`

Comment: Function is not getting deployed after adding this